# How to use glog with bazel?

Tags: c++, bazel, glog

I was able to install `glog` with:

`brew install glog`

Then I can successfully compile and use it using g++:

`g++ src/main/main_logger.cc -std=c++17  -lglog`

How can I do this with `bazel`?

I get this error:

```
fatal error: 'glog/logging.h' file not found
#include <glog/logging.h>
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

#### UPDATE:

Instead of installing and building `glog` locallay, I ended up referencing it as a git repo in the `WORKSPACE` file:

```
git_repository(
    name = "glog",
    remote = "https://github.com/google/glog.git",
    tag = "v0.5.0",
)
```

Now I can depend on it in my `cc_binary` rules like this:

```
cc_binary(
    name = "main_logger",
    srcs = ["main_logger.cc"],
    deps = [
        "//src/lib:CPPLib",
        "@com_github_gflags_gflags//:gflags",
        "@glog",
    ],
)
```

Complete example [here](https://github.com/ourarash/cpp-template).

Comment: You need to also set the `-I`nclude path to include wherever you put the library's headers.

Comment: I don't need `-I` with g++. It just works.

Comment: What do you mean? You ran `bazel src/main/main_logger.cc -std=c++17  -lglog`? For that I would expect an entirely different error message (about `src/main/main_logger.cc` not being known). You may need to elaborate a bit more what you're trying to do and what have you done trying to get it.
Generally, you want to declare an [external dependency](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/external.html) for use as `deps` of code you're trying to build in your tree. Alternatively, you can rely on the host configuration in which case you need to make sure your toolchain is configured correctly.

Answer (score 1):

There is already a doc about to use glog within a project which uses the Bazel build tool. [link](https://github.com/google/glog#bazel)

Then you can create a BUILD file, and use `bazel build //src/main:main_logger` to build it.

```
cc_binary(
    name = "main_logger",
    srcs = ["main_logger.cc"],
    deps = ["@com_github_google_glog//:glog"],
)
```